# Problem with Blender Guru Tutorial

Tags: mesh

I started to follow the Blender Guru Donut tutorial.
At this point in the video https://youtu.be/R2qjqqfkH6E?t=310 He talks about mesh intercepting other mesh.I was wondering if this is what he was talking about. Also when he told to Use Control + L
to select the mesh instead of selecting the top part it selected all the vertices.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FQAi.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDmrl.jpg

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: I think the blender guru course is very good, but I recommend you see the one on this page that I found if you handle Spanish, it is super complete and detailed.
Here you can find the course: [Blender 3D](https://3dblender.info/) I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

He's referring to a possible problem before the icing is properly separated from the donut.  The tutorial instructions are to:

1. Select the top half of the donut with the mouse in edit mode using X-ray
2. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the selected part of the mesh only
3. Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> or right mouse-click to leave the duplicated part in its original position, overlapping the original full mesh of the donut.
4. Use <kbd>P</kbd> -> Selection to separate the still-selected, duplicated mesh from the donut, to create a separate icing object.

Judging from your videos, you already did this correctly and have successfully separated the donut and icing objects.  So, you should switch from Edit Mode to Object Mode and skip ahead to 6:05 to continue with the tutorial.

If you want to understand the problem he's talking about, some people make a mistake between steps 3 and 4 by clicking on another part of the donut, so they lose the selection on their duplicated future icing *before* separating it from the donut object.  Now, they discover that they have trouble selecting the icing again, particularly because it overlaps the original donut, and both meshes are part of the same object.

They can't use box-select, because it will select vertices from both the duplicated icing and the original donut.  They can't even select individual vertices of the icing, not only because it would take forever, but because the icing vertices and donut vertices overlap, and it's very difficult to figure out which one is being selected.

A solution is to select a single vertex.  If you're lucky, it might be an icing vertex.  If you're unlucky, it might be a donut vertex, since they overlap.  You can tell by paying careful attention to the edge highlighting, or grabbing it and moving it around.  If you select a donut vertex by accident, you can re-click on the same vertex position, and Blender will normally switch to the icing vertex.  Once you having an icing vertex selected, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked vertices, re-selecting the entire icing mesh.

Note that this only works this way before the donut and icing meshes are separated into different objects.  In your case, you have already successfully separated the icing, and you are in edit mode with the donut object.  Because the icing vertices are in a separate object, you aren't able to select them at all, so any vertex you click on will be a donut vertex.  If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> it will select the entire donut because the whole donut mesh is connected.  It won't select the icing, because it's in a different object.

Fortunately, you don't *need* to select the icing, because it's already been separated, so you should just continue with the rest of the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks but the Donut mesh is intersecting the icing mesh.
Here in this vid i took https://imgur.com/a/Q0fkuyy

Comment: That type of intersection is unrelated to what he's talking about with this Ctrl-L business.  Keep watching the tutorial after 6:05.  You haven't reached the part where he pulls the icing mesh away from the donut so they no longer "intersect" this way.